# Remove all images from my word document without losing the data formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I just want to remove all the images in my word document. I have about 365 pages document, in which there are images in almost all pages. I can not delete one by one. I can save it in .txt format but I will lose the formatting of the data. Is there any other way to get this?

Comment: You probably didn't mean flat out, "remove all images..without losing formatting" as your title was, because obviously if you remove images, you will lose some formatting like the blank space where the image was, will go, but I guess you want that to go anyway, so you want to lose that formatting. Dan-o's answer seems good to me.

Answer (score 13):

In advanced find/replace
find ^g
replace  [leave blank]

Comment: This is exactly what the linked article in the accepted answer says. (OTOH, it's probably useful to have it written out here in case the link breaks.)

Answer (score 8):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2. Click on "More >>"
   [image]
3. Click on "Special" > "Graphic"
   [image]
4. Now you can see `^g` in "Find what:". Click on "Replace All"
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

---

```
Public Sub PicturesDeleteAll()

Dim objPic As Shape

    For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            objPic.Delete
    Next objPic

End Sub
```

For Inline Shapes, replace "Shape" with "InlineShape" and ".Shapes" with ".InlineShapes"

---